# How to construct pairs in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an expression like this,

```
    input = x[1] x[2]^3 x[5]^2;
```

Fist step, we can get a list from the input expression,

```
    list0={x[1],x[2],x[2],x[2],x[5],x[5]};

    list1 = {1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5};
```

Second step, I want to get all possible pairs in a new list2. Namely, we divide Length[list1]/2 parts in list1 and combine the possible sublist in a new list.   Of course, Length[list1]===Even.

```
   list2 = {{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {5, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {2, 5}} , {{1, 5}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}}};
```

Last step, we get the output expression,

```
   output = f[1, 2] f[2, 2] f[5, 5] + f[1, 2] f[2, 5]^2 + f[1, 5] f[2, 2] f[2, 5];
```

How can I transform the input expression into the output result?
Can you show me a simple method that will work for the general problem as well as my example?

In addition, we take another example,

```
    list1 = {1, 1, 2, 4};
```

the list2 should be

```
   list2 = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 4}};
```

Comment: How did you decide to break `list2` into three sublists?

Comment: The relationship between `list1` and `list2` is not obvious to me. Could you give some further explanation?

Comment: @einbandi. You're right. However, it was a typo. It's really how `list2` is derived the bothers me.

Comment: Wouldn't "all" possible pairs from list2 be this?: `Tuples[list1, 2] // Union`, yielding `{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 
  5}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to get from `input` to `list1`:

```
list1=# & @@@ Flatten[List @@ input /. Power -> ConstantArray]
(* {1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5} *)
```

One possible way (without the `Combinatorica` package and probably not very efficient) to get from `list1` to `list2`:

```
list2 = Union[
  Select[Subsets[Tuples[list1, {2}], {Length@list1/2}], 
   Sort@Flatten@# == Sort@list1 &], 
  SameTest -> (Sort[Sort /@ #1] == Sort[Sort /@ #2] &)]
(* {{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {5, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {2, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}}} *)
```

And then, borrowing from [kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kguler)'s answer:

```
output=Total@((Times @@ f @@@ #) & /@ list2)
(* f[1, 5] f[2, 2] f[2, 5] + f[1, 2] f[2, 5]^2 + f[1, 2] f[2, 2] f[5, 5] *)
```

**Edit:**
This updated version should be more general. It works with your second example, too.

**Edit 2:**
To get around the problem adressed in the comments you can use this version of `list1`. It works just as the earlier version, but also includes the case of only one summand (i.e. the head of `input` is no longer `Plus`):

```
input2 = x[1]^2;
newlist1 = # & @@@ Flatten[{input2} /. {Plus -> Sequence, Power -> ConstantArray}]
(* {1, 1} *)
```

Comment: Very nice!　This is just what I want. Thanks!

Comment: I find a problem. When input=x[1]^2, we cannot get the correct list1.

Comment: Please take a look at the edited post. I have made the solution more general to include single terms such as your example `x[1]^2`.

Comment: f[num_Integer] :=
   Union[Select[Subsets[Tuples[Range[2 num], {2}], {num}], 
    Sort@Flatten@# == Sort@Range[2 num] &], 
   SameTest -> (Sort[Sort /@ #1] == Sort[Sort /@ #2] &)]; Can you find a more simple method?

Comment: `f[num_Integer] := 
 Union[Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[Range@num], 
  SameTest -> (Sort[Sort /@ #1] == Sort[Sort /@ #2] &)]`

Answer (score 2):

I take it that the OP gets from list1 to list2 by just taking all distinct partitions in pairs (i.e. the set of all 3 pairs forming list1 when joined). Being lazy, I load

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

and then

```
list2 = Union[
Sort /@ Cases[KSetPartitions[#, Length@#/2], 
  x_ /; (Min[#] == Max[#] &@(Length /@ x))]] &@list1
```

which results in the desired output:

> {{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {5, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {2, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 
>      2}, {2, 5}}}

I am sure there is an easier way but let's see if that's what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer:

```
input = x[1] x[2]^3 x[5]^2;
list1 = Flatten[input/.Power|Times->List /.{x[a_], b_}:>ConstantArray[a, {b}] /. x[a_] :> a]
(* {1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5} *)

list2 = {{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {5, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {2, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}}};
output=Total@((Times @@ f @@@ #) & /@ list2)
(* f[1, 5] f[2, 2] f[2, 5] + f[1, 2] f[2, 5]^2 + f[1, 2] f[2, 2] f[5, 5] *)
```

Missing: how to get `list2` from `list1` pending clarification from the OP

Comment: I think `list2` has ordered subsets of length 2 of `list1` so that each element of `list1` is selected at most once

Answer (score 0):

```
constructPairs[input_] := Block[{func, f, list1, permutepart, list2},
func[x[t_]] := t;
func[x[t_]^m_] := ConstantArray[t, m];

list1 = Flatten[Map[func]@Cases[input, p : (t_x | x[_]^_) :> p]];
permutepart = Apply[Partition[{##}, 2] &, Permutations[list1], {1}];
list2 = DeleteDuplicates@*Map[Sort]@Cases[permutepart, p : {{_, _} ..} :> Map[Sort, p]];

Plus @@ Times @@@ Apply[f, list2, {2}]
];
```

supplying input to function:

```
input = x[1] x[2]^3 x[5]^2;
constructPairs[input]

(* f[1, 5] f[2, 2] f[2, 5] + f[1, 2] f[2, 5]^2 + f[1, 2] f[2, 2] f[5, 5] *)
```